# C++: Trying to encapsulate std::enable_if in class

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, template-aliases

I was just using SFINAE to select function templates when I had the glorious idea to encapsulate `std::enable_if` in a struct like this

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct EnableWhenEqual
{
    typedef typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, U>::value>::type type;
};
```

and then use it, for example, like this

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename Enable = EnableWhenEqual<T,U>::type >
void foo(T&& t, U&& u)
{
    if (std::is_same<T,U>::value)
        std::cout << "OK, overload allowed." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Bad. Should not compile!" << std::endl;
}
```

However, this doesn't work, as one sees by invoking

```
foo(1,1);     //prints "OK, overload allowed"
foo(1,2.0);   //prints "Bad, should not compile", but obviously does
```

On the other hand, by trying to create

```
EnableWhenEqual<int,int>();      //compiles
EnableWhenEqual<int,double>();   //does not compile because type does not exist
```

one obtains a compiler error ("type is not a member of std::enable_if").

What is the reason for this behaviour? I'm asking because from my little SFINAE knowledge I would have thought that an error in the type-deduction leads to exclusion of the overload ... ?

---

For completeness, the above problem can be solved using template aliasing

```
template <typename T, typename U>
using EnableWhenEqual = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,U>::value>::type;
```

Is there also an alternative using a struct instead of a template alias?

**EDIT:** Here I mean an implementation which solves the general problem. For example, this here

```
template<typename T, typename U, bool B, typename C=void>
struct EnableWhenEqual {};

template<typename T, typename U, typename C>
struct EnableWhenEqual<T,U,std::is_same<T,U>::value>
{
    typedef typename C type;
};
```

don't works for me because the partial specialization needs a simple identifier. If it would, one could replace `std::is_same` by general structs `Condition<T,U>`. Any alternatives?

Comment: Since you're missing a `typename` before the `EnableWhenEqual` default argument, I'm guessing you're using some VS version older than 2013. Once you add the `typename`, your code [fails to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2c296e2d8de0ec0) on both gcc and clang, as well as VS2013 (`error C2783: 'void foo(T &&,U &&)' : could not deduce template argument for 'Enable'`)

Comment: Using `EnableWhenEqual<T,U>::type` requires instantiating `EnableWhenEqual`, which leads to instantiating all member declarations. The member typedef will sometimes not be legal, but this error does not occur in the immediate context of the function template `foo` (SFINAE == SFITICINAE = Substitution Failure In The Immediate Context Is Not An Error).

Comment: You can of course replicate what `enable_if` is doing, i.e. use template specialization: `template<typename T, typename U> struct EnableWhenEqual {}; template<typename T> struct EnableWhenEqual<T,T> { using type = void; };`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Adding typename indeed leads to compiler errors as explained by dyp. Regarding the question for a struct - based implementation, I was looking not for this special example but for a general solution.I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: What's wrong with using `std::enable_if` and `std::enable_if_t` (C++14)? or template aliases? Why would one ever want something like `enable_if_same<>`? Its only advantage that it's slightly shorter than `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<>::value>`, but it introduces yet another type traits to remember, though it's trivially constructed from existing ones.

Comment: @Walter: Nothing's wrong with it, except that template parameter lists can get quite long. Therefore I was seeking for an alternative where the conditions are evaluated in a neatly arranged way -- which is also not the case for the derived-from-`enable_if` solution. Besides, of course, a type-trait is advantageous if one evaluate the condition many times, which is the case in my code.

Comment: As a style point, you don't need to give the template parameter a name if it's not referenced in the definition: `template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if<...>::type> void foo(T&& v) {...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct EnableWhenEqual : std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, U>::value>
{
};
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/650202ba3d42d34b

Answer (score 2):

A different kind of encapsulation:

```
template<class T, class U>
using EnableWhenEqual_t = typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<T,U>::value >::type;

template<typename T, typename U, typename Enable = EnableWhenEqual_t<T,U> >
void foo(T&& t, U&& u) {
  if (std::is_same<T,U>::value)
    std::cout << "OK, overload allowed." << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "Bad. Should not compile!" << std::endl;
}
```

note when you are asking questions about VS treatment of templates, please include the exact visual studio version.  VS template support is extremely quirky.